# How to remove brackets in their content from a string in php

Tags: php

I get strings like following:

```
New York (25,00 &#8364;), London (25,00 &#8364;), ....
```

I need the remove the brackets with their inner content, so that only city names separeted by commas remain.

I could only find solutions to find and replace particular characters, but nothing that can solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am finding the open bracket and getting the position by using `strpos` function and then find the close bracket position in the string. then by having both start and ending I minus end position to start + 1 .
At the end by using `substr_replace` function I replace nothing to characters in the string from position that bracket starts till the end of it.

```
$string = 'New York (25,00 &#8364;)';
$from = '(';
$to = ')';
$findposfrom = strpos($string, $from);
$findposto = strpos($string, $to);
$length = ($findposto - $findposfrom)+1;
$replace = '';
$stringreplace = substr_replace($string, $replace, $findposfrom, $length);

echo $findposfrom.'</br>';
echo $findposto.'</br>';
echo $length.'</br>';
echo $stringreplace;
```